# pd.DataFrameを、比率を示す図に再構築したい

Tags: python3, pandas

pandas.DatFrameで作成したクロス図について、以下のように、
a行、b行それぞれの比率を表すクロス図に再構築したいと思っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

作業を何ステップに分け（無理やり）できましたが、
もっと、シンプルに記述する方法は、ないでしょうか。
よろしく、お願いいたします。

```
import pandas as pd
lst=[[120,80,300],[280,120,400]]
df1=pd.DataFrame(lst,index=['a','b'],columns=['A','B','合計'])
df1
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
#A列、B列を抽出する
df2=df1.loc[:,['A','B']]
df2
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
#それぞれを比率にする
df3= ((df.div(df.sum(1),axis=0)))
df3
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
# 「合計」列を追加する
df4=df3.assign(合計=1.0)
df4
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下は [pandas.DataFrame.div](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html#pandas-dataframe-div) を使う方法です。

※ `120 + 80 = 200` なので `lst` を一部修正しています。

```py
lst = [[120,80,200],[280,120,400]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst,index=['a','b'],columns=['A','B','合計'])

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
print(df1.div(df1['合計'], axis=0))

#
     A    B  合計
a  0.6  0.4   1.0
b  0.7  0.3   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

各行に対してapplyすることでlambda式で列の比率を求めることができます。

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [[120,80,200],[280,120,400]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst, index=['a','b'], columns=['A','B','合計'])
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x : [x[c] / x['合計'] for c in df1], axis=1)
print(df2)

#出力結果
a    [0.6, 0.4, 1.0]
b    [0.7, 0.3, 1.0]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

まず, 合計を算出するところから。
割合は, 前の行との比較・割合なら pandasで用意されてるものがあるけど, このような場合は見つからなかったので普通に計算

```py
import pandas as pd
lst=[[120,80], [280,120]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, index=['a','b'], columns=['A','B'])

df['合計'] = df.sum(axis=1)
for item in ['A', 'B']:
    df[f'{item}(割合)'] = df[item] / df['合計']

display(df)
print()
df[['A(割合)', 'B(割合)', '合計']]
```

[image: 結果]